# Using Java regex to validate date from a long string

Tags: java, regex, date

I'm trying to write a Java routine that can parse out dates from a long string, i.e. given the string:

```
"Please have the report to me by 6/15, because the shipment comes in on 6/18"
```

The regex would find both 6/15 and 6/18. I've looked on Stack Overflow and elsewhere, and most examples of a date regex simply verify whether a given string is a date or not, rather than finding dates within a larger amount of text. Ideally, I'd want a regex that could identify all of the main ways people numerically write dates i.e `6/15`, `6/15/12`, `06/15/12`, `15/6/12`, `15/06/12`, although perhaps it would be best to separate these into different regexes for the purpose of cla. I'm new to regexes (I just started learning about them two days ago) and regexes are still a bit cryptic to me, so I'd appreciate a detailed explanation of any regex suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not bothering with range checking, this suffices:

```
(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})(?:/(\d{4}|\d{2}))?
```

To check that you can't do `2/29/2001` but can do `2/29/2000`, you really want to do it after the regexp has done its job, or you're going to end up in an asylum.

EDIT: Better yet, for isolating the century, and protecting against things like 2/193 (prompted by Alex's question, even though it's a separate issue):

```
\b(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})(?:/(\d{2})?(\d{2}))?\b
```

You'd get 4 captures in each match: `[month, day, century, year]`, where `century` and `year` could be empty.

Comment: Both of your dates are the same. Do you mean `2001` and `2000`?

Comment: Won't this match twice on "6/18/2012" - once for "6/18" and once for "18/20"? Any way to prevent that?

Comment: @Alex: Regexps don't work like that, in any engine that I know of. Matches can't overlap. (You can fake overlapping by using lookaheads/lookbehinds, but the matches themselves are still disjunct.)

Answer (score 0):

```
\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}(?:/(?:\d{2}){1,2})?
```

Here's the breakdown:

- `\d{1,2}` matches 1 or 1 digits
- `/`  followed by a `/`
- `\d{1,2}` followed 1 or 2 more digits
- `(?:/(?:\d{2}){1,2})?` followed by an optional slash and 2 or 4 digit year

From the matches, you'll probably want to parse them with Java DateParse instead of trying to put all the validation rules in the regex.

You may want to protect against fractions as well `1/4th`
This can be done by appending a negative lookahead to your regex: `(?!th|rd|nd)` which causes the regex to not match if followed by `th`, `rd`, or `nd`.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your question? You should read some guide about regex first.

You need a method that returns every match in the String like this:
p is the regex, text is your text.

```
private LinkedList<String> matches(String p, String text) {
    LinkedList<String> results = new LinkedList<String>();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(p);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        results.add(matcher.group());
    }

    return results;
}
```

You can separate each date-pattern with |

If you put a part of your regex into braces (...), this part is treated as a "group".
So you can extract single numbers out of the matching string (if you want to).